# ZFC's Axiom Schema of Separation/Specification Implies Contradiction?

Tags: logic, set-theory

The Axiom Schema of Separation is: $\forall a \forall \Psi (x) \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in a \space \land \Psi (y))$. If we make $a:=\{\emptyset\}$, $\Psi (x) :\leftrightarrow \lnot y \in x$, $x:=x$ and $y :=\emptyset$, we get the following: $y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in \{\emptyset\} \space \land \lnot y \in x$. This in turn implies: $y \in x \leftrightarrow \lnot y \in x$, which is contradictory and should negate the Axiom due to Modus Tollendo Tollens. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The genuine axiom scheme of separation requires that the formula used to specify the elements of the "separated" set does not refer to that set.

A correct statement of the scheme is

$$\forall z_1\cdots \forall z_k\forall a\exists x\forall y(y\in x\leftrightarrow y\in a\land \Psi(y,z_1,\ldots,z_k))$$

where $\Psi(y,z_1,\ldots,z_k)$ is a formula whose free variables are drawn from $y,z_1,\ldots,z_k$.

Comment: ... and the condition is necessari exactly to avoid the above "misuse"; see Patrick Suppes, [Axiomatic set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA21) (1960), page 21 for the same example.

Comment: ...hey, nice reference!

Comment: Then, why is the Axiom Schema of Abstraction ($(\forall \psi (x) \exists y \forall a)(a \in y \iff \psi (a))$) replaced by a the Axiom Schema of Separation, when it could only be extended to saying that the property $\psi (x)$ cannot refer to the set being constructed?

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant in this topic and thanks for your answer.

Comment: I didn't say that naive comprehension could be rescued by adding that proviso alone.  E.g. naive comprehension under the proviso still leaves Russell's paradox.  By the way, note that putting a quantification over properties as you do makes the statement no longer a first-order schema but a second-order formula.

Comment: I've tried, without success, to get Russell's paradox with naive comprehension, with that proviso added. Can you show me how it's done?

Comment: You may be overthinking it.  Naive comprehension (or the relevant kind of case) says $\exists x\forall y(y\in x\leftrightarrow \Phi(y)$; here the proviso comes to that $\Phi$ not contain $x$.  But that's fine with the Russell construction, which picks for $\Phi$ the formula $y\notin y$.

Comment: Hey. Thanks so much. Can I contact you for further questions in set theory?

Comment: What is the difference between a first-order schema and a second order formula?